# Unbind an event bound with Ember.run.bind?

Tags: ember.js

I have a component that has to react to viewport changes.

The naive approach would be to just bind a jQuery resize listener, but that could mess with the Ember run loop.

The best practice approach is to use [`Ember.run.bind`](http://emberjs.com/blog/2014/02/12/ember-1-4-0-and-ember-1-5-0-beta-released.html#toc_ember-run-bind)

This works just fine, but I wonder how to unbind such an event once the component is no longer active?

Comment: Why is ur controller reacting to viewport changes. Components or views are what normally should react to viewport changes. Views provide hook like willDestroyElement to unbind events. For reference https://github.com/truenorth/ember-resize https://github.com/taras/ember-resize-mixin

Comment: Edited to read "component" instead of "controller". The question remains the same. How do I unbind the event once it's bound via `Ember.run.bind`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Figured this out. `Ember.run.bind` doesn't actually need an unbind method, you can just unbind the jQuery event.

Code example:

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  _resizeListener: null,

  didInsertElement: function(){
    // keep a reference to the event listener
    this._resizeListener = Ember.run.bind(this, this.preformLayout);
    Ember.$(window).on('resize', this._resizeListener);
  },

  willDestroy: function(){
    if(this._resizeListener){
      // whenever component gets destroyed, unbind the listener
      Ember.$(window).off('resize', this._resizeListener);
    }
  }
});
```